# Gitlab Call Upstream Project from Downstream

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline

Does anyone have an example of how you can trigger an upstream project's CI from a downstream project? So if there is a commit to the downstream project, run the pipeline in the upstream project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact a project is downstream or upstream should not matter in case of a [**Multi-project pipelines**](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/downstream_pipelines.html#multi-project-pipelines).

That uses the [`trigger` keyword](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#trigger)

```yaml
trigger-multi-project-pipeline:
  trigger: my-group/my-project
```